# How to pass type which got FromJSON implemented as argument to anoter function?

Tags: haskell, interface

Here is my try:

```
decode :: String -> FromJSON a => BS.ByteString -> a
decode fnm iFromJSONable = do
    ymlData <- BS.readFile fnm
    let ymlDecode :: Maybe iFromJSONable
        ymlDecode = Data.Yaml.decode ymlData 
    return fromJust ymlDecode
```

error:

```
Couldn't match type `a' with `IO b0'
  `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
      the type signature for
        Yaml.decode :: String -> FromJSON a => BS.ByteString -> a
      at src\Yaml.hs:46:11
Expected type: IO BS.ByteString -> (BS.ByteString -> IO b0) -> a
  Actual type: IO BS.ByteString
               -> (BS.ByteString -> IO b0) -> IO b0
In a stmt of a 'do' block: ymlData <- BS.readFile fnm
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing up types and values here. You cannot treat a class constraint such as `FromJSON` as an argument (`iFromJSONable`) and then use it in a local type signature as well.

I guess you want this:

```
decode :: FromJSON a => FilePath -> IO a
decode fnm = do
    ymlData <- BS.readFile fnm
    let ymlDecode = Data.Yaml.decode ymlData 
    return (fromJust ymlDecode)
```

You are reading data from a file specified by a string (`FilePath` is just a synonym for `String`). You are getting an IO action that can produce any type `a` that is an instance of the `FromJSON` class. Which type that is is going to be determined by the context in which you use the `decode` function.